# Conditional sum in slick (scala)

Tags: sql, scala, slick

I'm trying to rewrite following SQL into slick:

```
SELECT id
SUM(
 if (spend > 0, 1, 0)
)
FROM items
GROUP by id
```

My current code looks similar to this:

```
items.groupBy(r => r.id).map {
  case (id, group) => (id, group.map { r => if (r.spend > 0) 1 else 0 }.sum)
}
```

But I got following error:

`polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [R]slick.lifted.Rep[R]
 required: Boolean`

I also tried to use `filter` and `length`, but with no success. How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slick already provides solution for this ([documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/api/#slick.lifted.Case$)):

```
items.groupBy(r => r.id).map {
  case (id, group) => (id, group.map { r => 
    Case If r.spend > BigDecimal(0.0) Then 1 Else 0 
  }.sum)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Scala ternary expression could not be transferred to slick syntax.

Simplest approach is just to simplify the query here to

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM items
WHERE spend > 0
GROUP by id
```

Corresponding slick will be

```
items.filter(_.spend > 0).groupBy(_.id) map {
      case (id, group) => (id, group.size)
    }
```

Or you could try to get access to the `if` function using `SimpleFunction`:

```
def ifFun[T] = SimpleFunction.ternary[Boolean, T, T, T]("if")

items.groupBy(_.id) map {
  case (id, group) => (id, group.map(r => ifFun(r.spend > 0, 1, 0)).sum)
}
```

Comment: The query of course could be simplified, but actually my real query is much more complex with multiple joins. The second solution might be useful, I'll give a try.

Comment: Ok, I got it: `Case If r.spend > BigDecimal(0.0) Then 1 Else 0`